# WordPress Cron Job in Bookly Plugin

Tags: cron

Hell, Friends. I am using [WordPress Bookly Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool/). I want to send emails to customers daily using cron. Plugin is aksing this words to me "**To send scheduled notifications please execute the following script hourly with your cron: php -f C:\wamp\www\multan-academy\wp-content\plugins\bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool\lib\utils\send_notifications_cron.php**". Here, is the code for that file. What should I include or call here.

```
<?php
define('SHORTINIT', true);


/**
 * Class Notifications
 */
class Notifications
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }



}

$notifications = new Notifications();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a cron job on the server to do what the plugin authors are asking you to do: execute the php command they've given you. Just make sure you're not setting up WordPress's `wp_cron()`, since this one is not a real cron job. From [this article](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/):

> When it comes to WordPress, you can schedule an event to happen at a
>   certain interval, but it doesn’t operate like a classical cron job.
>
> Instead, the event is set and scheduled and written to the database.
>   The next time a user hits the site, the WordPress cron system will
>   look to see if an event is scheduled and, if so, will then fire the
>   event.
>
> Notice the problem?
>
> Someone has to visit the site before the event actually kicks off. So
>   if you’ve scheduled something to happen hourly, but no one has visited
>   your site in the last hour, then the event will never kick off.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Author is asking for " please execute the following script hourly with your cron". Can you please guide me how do i execute this script.

Comment: This is not WordPress-related. You can search and find countless tutorials on how to set up a cron job to run on your particular server.